# Can I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll for word automation?

Tags: java, ms-word

I have multiple word documents. I want to fetch some parts from all word documents based on some keywords and need to write all extracted parts to single output word document in java.

Is it possible to do this using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll?

How can I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll in java?

Comment: Java or JavaScript?  Your tag collection makes little sense.

Comment: I want to implement it using java. How can I use interop word dll in java?

Comment: Not a clue but I've adjusted your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jacob.

I've successfully used it to automate Word to save a docx as a PDF, following [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/jacob-project/discussion/375946/thread/751c8bfb/).

But for the task you describe, you'd probably be better off with [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org) (with which I'm involved) or POI - especially if you are trying to do this server-side, or in an environment where the client PC environment is unknown.  But you're familiar with those already :-)